# error while doing bufferreader with Json Object

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I'm having error with my project and it seems to be from this portion of my code

```
try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
```

after this I parse the string to a jsonobject

can somebody gives a hand here plz

and this is my logcat "error" file

02-05 17:46:27.286: E/Buffer Error(527): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/JSON Parser(527): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at com.example.androidhive.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:65)
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-05 17:46:27.286: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

this is my loginacticvity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
Button btnLogin;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            Log.d("Button", "Login");
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");


                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

this is the loginuser method

```
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    Log.d("JSON", "issa");
    return json;
}
```

here is the gestjsonfromurl

```
 public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: post the logcat what is the error??

Comment: where is LoginActivity.java:65 line in current code ?

Comment: are u using AsyncTask for getting json from server and what is LoginActivity.java:65 line in current code ?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K this one       loginErrorMsg.setText("");

Comment: @user1794499 : make sure u are getting result in Log.e("JSON", json); line just  check log

Comment: that's the problem I don't get Log.e("JSON", json) rather I get the exception msg

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K but I can't join due to lack of sufficient reputations :'(

Comment: @user1794499 : ok u will need to first try to get data from webservice post your loginUser method code

Comment: @user1794499 : also post getJSONFromUrl method code friend

Comment: I post it in the original post...thanks alot buddy

Comment: @user1794499 : use http://pastebin.com/tZD3i832 code instead of getJSONFromUrl method and check in log what u are getting in response from server

Comment: @user1794499 : sir have u tried it ? any success?

Comment: but how can I parse the string to the JSON object!!!!is't possible to add it here because I have it in my original code.....sorry for my too many questions but I really need a help

Comment: @user1794499 : i think u don't known how we debug code . i told you tell me what u are getting in response from server when u are using my suggested code but u have not told me ? because if you get right response from server then u convert it to json Object . now tell me what u are getting in response

Comment: but I can't run it due to error at this line JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);

Comment: @user1794499 : friend just comment this code first testing

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K but this code is part of the whole project and I have JSON object pinned in many files so I have to comment my code but I will left with nothing to run>>>I guess is better if I send you the other parts so you have a clear picture of the matter.....is that ok,buddy!!!!

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K I'm still waiting your response dude...please complete your good work,I really appreciate your guidance

Answer (score 0):

ADD :
if(json != null)
Before :
 if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null)